# Dividing numpy 2D array into finer resolution

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array (2 x 2) elements, I want to create another 2D numpy array out of it, such that:

2D array:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.rand(2,2)
```

> > ```
> >   array([[10.0,8.0],
> >               [6.0,4.0]])
> > ```

I want to get a 4x4 array out of it such that all values of the finer resolution array corresponding to a specific cell of the coarser array, are the same as the coarser array:

> > ```
> >   array([[10.0,10.0,8.0,8.0],
> >             [10.0,10.0,8.0,8.0]
> >             [6.0,6.0,4.0,4.0]
> >             [6.0,6.0,4.0,4.0]])
> > ```

I could do this using for loops, but would really like to find out if a more pythonic way exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(2,2)
>>> a
array([[ 0.66172561,  0.09262421],
       [ 0.40578266,  0.84510431]])
>>> a.repeat(2, 0).repeat(2, 1)
array([[ 0.66172561,  0.66172561,  0.09262421,  0.09262421],
       [ 0.66172561,  0.66172561,  0.09262421,  0.09262421],
       [ 0.40578266,  0.40578266,  0.84510431,  0.84510431],
       [ 0.40578266,  0.40578266,  0.84510431,  0.84510431]])
```

Comment: Can your soln be extended to converting a 2x2 nump array to a 8x8 array?

Comment: Yes, first argument is the number of repetitions, the second argument is the axis. Array size does not matter.

Comment: great, this is super useful